TemplateSyntaxError at /display/displaymyoperations/ Could not parse the remainder: '(url)' from 'unquote(url)'
I am getting the following error when I want to show the operations that a user makes:
TemplateSyntaxError at /display/displaymyoperations/ Could not parse the remainder: '(url)' from 'unquote(url)'

This is views.py for myoprations
def displaymyoperations(request):
    # استرداد بيانات المستخدم الحالي
    current_user = request.user
    userprofile=UserProfile.objects.get(user=current_user)
    # استعلام بيانات العروض التي قام المستخدم بتقييمها
    display_data = Display_Data.objects.filter(users=userprofile).order_by('-puplish_date')

    #display_data = Display_Data.objects.filter(users=userprofile)
    # تحويل قيمة التقييم إلى نص وصفي
    for display_datum in display_data:
        if display_datum.choosenum == 1:
            display_datum.choosenum_text = "نجاح"
        elif display_datum.choosenum == 2:
            display_datum.choosenum_text = "فشل"
        elif display_datum.choosenum == 3:
            display_datum.choosenum_text = "بحاجة إلى مال"
        elif display_datum.choosenum == 4:
            display_datum.choosenum_text = "بحاجة إلى أدوات"
        else:
            display_datum.choosenum_text = "مؤجل"

   
    # تحضير سياق العرض (context)
    context = {
        'display_data': display_data,
         
    }

    # عرض القالب (template) مع البيانات
    return render(request, 'display/displaymyoperations.html', context)

and this is template
{% for display_datum in display_data %}
    {% if display_datum.displays.isyoutube %}
    {% with video_id=display_datum.displays.url|slice:"30:" %}
            <a href="{% url 'display_video' url=video_id %}" class="btn mt-3 w-100">{{ display_datum.displays.text }}</a>
        {% endwith %}
    {% else %}
    {% with url=display_datum.displays.url|stringformat:"s" %}
    <a href="{% url 'display_web' url=unquote(url) %}" class="btn mt-3 w-100">{{ display_datum.displays.text }}</a>
{% endwith %}


        
    {% endif %}
    <strong>{{ display_datum.choosenum_text }}</strong> {{ display_datum.puplish_date }}<br>
{% endfor %}

The problem is raise on display_web although display_video is the same I don't know why this error occurs, this is display_web in views.py:
def display_web(request, url):
    # تشكيل الـ URL الكامل لإطار الفيديو على YouTube
    full_url = unquote(url)

    # استخراج عنوان الموقع من URL
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(full_url).content, "html.parser")
    title = soup.title.text
    countArry=check_url_exists_and_evluate(full_url)
    Darry=check_url_exists_and_date(full_url)
    
    data = mydata(full_url, title, countArry, Darry)
    return render(request, 'display/webviewA.html', {'data':data })

and this is the urls of display_web
re_path(r'^display_web/(?P<url>.+)$',views.display_web, name='display_web'),

